A simple bound on the proportion of primes less than $2^k$.
Fix $k > 1$ and let $P = \{x \mid 0 \le x < 2^k - 1 \text{ and } x \text{ is prime }\}$. Then I want to show that $$ \frac{|P|}{2^k} \ge \frac{1}{2k}. $$
I know how to prove this by using Bertrand's Postulate but I expect that there is a more elementary way of showing this too. For context, I encountered this while reading some introductory lecture notes on probability– these notes claim that the proof is easy and say that it has been relegated to an assignment (which I don't have access too). I would really appreciate some hints!

Shouldn't your definition of $P$ have $x$ instead of $m$ in the inequality and instead of $k$ in the requirement to be prime?  Please reread your question and use the edit button below it to correct.

Sorry for the typos. Should be fixed now!

I don't even think Bertrand's postulate is enough—something like Chebyshev's bounds for the prime-counting function $\pi(x)$ seems necessary.

$\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\ln(x)}$ approaches $1$ from above. So $\frac{\pi(2^k)}{2^k/[k \ln(2)]}$ approaches $1$ from above. So $\frac{\pi(2^k)}{2^k/k}$ approaches $1/\ln(2)$ from above. So asymptotically, $\frac{\pi(2^k)}{2^k}\sim\frac{1}{k\ln(2)}$. So the bound you seek is only different from this by a scalar multiple, and it seems like it may be hard to establish that without similar machinery that goes into proving the prime number theorem.
